# Getting facebook event comments

Tags: ruby, facebook

I am trying to make a GET requests to get all comments from an event on facebook through facebooks Graph API Explorer to later implement this in ruby. However each event gives me the id of the event. I did though manage to get all comments from one particular event.

```
{
  "id": "406000089699838"
}
```

Any ideas? Do I need any particular access tokens for this?

Sometimes I only get a empty json like this:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

Comment: What API call are you making?

Comment: A GET request. I am simply following their instructions on:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event

Comment: Then update your question with the exact API call you are making